# Custom control border doesn't show if Update() is called, but shows if Refresh() is called

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, gdi

I've drawn a border around a Custom Control, but now when I try to draw a small rectangle inside of the Custom Control after (or even before) drawing the initial border, it does not draw/get displayed on the Control when the mouse is moving over the Control.

I put a `Console.WriteLine(...)` in the `OnPaint` method to see if it's being hit, but nothing is output to the Console/Output Pane. The only time it output anything was when the `Control` first loaded. But then if the else clause is being hit, why doesn't the small rectangle get drawn when the mouse *is* moving over the `Control`?

You can safely ignore anything inside the Borders region, thus the code is not shown.

```
namespace JTS.Controls
{
    public partial class ListBox : Control
    {
        public enum ListBoxBorders
        {
            Top,
            Bottom,
            Left,
            Right,
            All,
            None
        }

        ListBoxBorders SelectedListBoxBorder = ListBoxBorders.All;

        [Browsable(true)]
        [Description("Defines which borders are drawn onto the ListBox."), Category("Appearance")]
        public ListBoxBorders ListBoxBorder
        {
            get { return SelectedListBoxBorder; }
            set { SelectedListBoxBorder = value; }
        }

        public enum BorderStyles
        {
            Top,
            Bottom,
            Left,
            Right,
            All,
            None
        }

        Graphics graphics;

        protected bool mouseMoving;

        public ListBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ListBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handled.");
            mouseMoving = true;

            this.Update(); // it works if Refresh is called
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            graphics = pe.Graphics;

            #region Borders
            // logic to draw right-edge border.
            #endregion

            if (mouseMoving)
            {
                // ************************************
                // THIS PART NEVER GETS EXECUTED.
                // ************************************
                Console.WriteLine(mouseMoving.ToString());
                graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(
                            Color.Green, 1), new Rectangle(
                                5, 5, 50, 50));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mouseMoving.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
After I change `this.Update` to `this.Refresh`, everything works. Can somebody explain why?

Comment: I would not keep that graphics variable outside of the scope of the Paint event.  You can't do anything with it after the paint event is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand what's the difference and relationship among `Invalidate`, `Update` and `Refresh`. Here is a [very good blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/subhagpo/archive/2005/02/22/378098.aspx) about it, you can read my summary if you are lazy :)

In short: `Invaidate` only **invalidates the client area, but never update it**; `Update` will **update the invalidated client area to the new look**; `Refresh` essentially **ends up with calling** `Invalidate` **followed by** `Update`.

Now let's discuss things in details.

Before we look into your issue, let's look into how winforms control get painted.

All controls paint actually responses to [`WM_PAINT` messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As a short summary, this message is sent in the following conditions:

- `UpdateWindow` or `RedrawWindow` is called, or
- `DispatchMessage` dispatches a `WM_PAINT` from the message queue.

When a control gets a `WM_PAINT` message, it paints its background followed by the foreground if necessary, and then the `OnPaint` event is fired to perform user-defined custom painting.

With the background, let's talk about `Invalidate`, `Update` and `Refresh`.

> `Invalidate` ... essentially ends up calling one of the `RedrawWindow`, `InvaliateRect` or `InvalidateRgn` functions. If `RedrawWindow` is called then this may result in a `WM_PAINT` message being posted to the application message queue (to invalidate the child controls).

But noted here,  the function only "invalidate" or "dirty" the client area by **adding it to the current update region of the window of the control.** This invalidated region, along with all other areas in the update region, is marked for painting when the next `WM_PAINT` message is received. As a result you **may not** see your control refreshing (and showing the invalidation) immediately (or synchronously).

> `Update` calls `UpdateWindow` function which updates the client area of the control by sending `WM_PAINT` message to the window (of the control) if the window's update region is not empty. This function sends a `WM_PAINT` directly to `WndProc()` bypassing the application message queue.

Thus, if the window update region is previously “invalidated” then calling “update” would immediately "update" (and cause repaint) the invalidation.

Finally, `Refresh` chained functions above together: it calls `Invalidate` to invalidate the area, then calls `Update` to force a refresh.

Comment: This is a great answer, I appreciate you taking the time to explain in more detail the differences. Thank you!

Comment: welcome :) if it explains your puzzle, remember to mark it as answer so that others with the same doubt could benefit :D

Comment: Already marked :-) Out of curiosity, is your background in C++ by any chance?

Comment: actually it was my first language, but I just used it as an algorithm solving tool and didn't go that deep in C++ haha.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after posting my question, I thought to myself, "It may have something to do with calling `this.Update();`. I don't know why, but I changed it to `this.Refresh();` and it is now drawing the smaller rectangle as and when expected.